# How can I implement fare calculation in my cab-booking app? Not necessary, but for reference I am following simcoder from youtube

Tags: android, cab

I have implemented the code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRl3W5V9Q4c&lc=z22gw1gxlm3iilimwacdp43au1edt1ner1qfnff0on1w03c010c.1510919366304981

Now I need to implement fare estimation and FINAL fare calculation.
I want to make a fully functioning cab-booking app

I know it might hurt the eyes of some pros here, but I am a real newbie to coding, any help is appreciated.

Rates chart

[image]

i think I might need an if-else loop or switch, but a pro opinion would help

Thanks

Comment: As this does not reference the Uber-API, can you please remove that tag? Thanks!

Comment: @KyleDavis yes, sure. My bad.  It's done.